# Remove a short code and update it's content (AJAX)

Tags: shortcode, ajax, get-template-part

This is my code

```
function ajax_layoutcontrol(){

    if( !check_ajax_referer( 'special-string','security')){
        return wp_send_json_error( 'Invalid nounce');
    }
    if (! current_user_can('manage_options')){
        return wp_send_json_error('You are not allowed to do this');
    }

    $orderwppl= $_POST['order']; // This is an array['phone', 'email']


        remove_shortcode( 'sideblock' );
        add_shortcode( 'sideblock', 'new_order' );

     function new_order(){

        foreach ($orderwppl as $item) {
            get_template_part( 'content', $item ); 
        }

     }

    wp_send_json_success( 'Post Saved');
    die();


}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_save_listing_order', 'ajax_layoutcontrol');
```

i am tring to change the shortcode

```
function old_order(){
        get_template_part( 'content', 'email' ); 
        get_template_part( 'content', 'phone' );
}

add_shortcode('sideblock', 'old_order');
```

But this is not working as ajax throws 500 error
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Is your $_Post returning the array as expected?

From what I'm seeing your add_action isn't calling the right function either...

Either change `wpprolister_ajax_layoutcontrol` in that line to `ajax_layoutcontrol` or rename the function to `wpprolister_ajax_layoutcontrol`

Another option may be to put a selectbox meta on the page and use that to call the correct format though. then you don't need to use POST data.

ie

```
function new_order() {
  $template_check = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'template_check', true );
  get_template_part( 'content', $template_check ); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry that typo, i have tested $_POST it is returning the array correctly. some thing is going wrong in removing the shortcode and updating it. sorry that `ajax_layoutcontrol` was a typo..it's still not working

Comment: why replace the shortcode?  Just make a new one

Comment: Actually there is more stuff going on..There is a sortable list in the back-end and i am passing the list-id to $_POST by ajax and so foreach will change the shortcode accordingly( the template will change order).